# Disabling a DVD's built-in subtitles in VLC

Tags: vlc-media-player

When playing a DVD in VLC which came with unintelligibly translated English subtitles included, I am unable to disable them and use a .srt file instead. I am able to disable subtitles altogether, but upon trying to load and use a .srt the original subtitles are displayed instead.

How can I do this?

Thanks

edit: .srt, not .cue (which is an audio track-listing file)

Answer (score 1):

In menu Video -> Subtitles track, select disable.

If this doesn't work, it could be the subtitles are hardcoded into film.

To use external file with subtitles (such as srt) start DVD in VLC, select play and when film is actually playing, drag and drop the subtitles file onto VLC.

Comment: Thanks. I can play the DVD without any subtitle track at all, but my problem is that if I select a .cue file to use then it always reverts to playing the subtitle track that came on the DVD

Comment: Where is this cue file located? Subtitles that are on DVD should be accessible from the subtitles menu in VLC. Also as far as I know cue files have nothing to do with subtitles.

Comment: I'm trying not to use the subtitles on the DVD, as they are such a bad translation that they are completely useless.

Sorry, by .cue I meant .srt (.cue is somewhat of an equivalent for audio files)

Comment: I tried it with one of my DVDs. I started normally, selected play and when movie started playing (after all the logos and such) I dragged srt subtitles into the window and they played fine. I even got additional menu entry in Subtitles track. I added the info into my post.

Answer (score 0):

The subtitle file is probably a .srt file. Can you find that and delete it? It might mean copying the DVD files to hard disk and then deleting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with a full DVD (eg, including the menus).  If this is a DVD on a disc, you'll need to open it as a "DVD", not as a "DVD (menus)".  You can probably do something similar if it's DVD-contents-on-a-harddrive.

- Go to File >> Open Disc
- Select "DVD" (not "DVD (menus)") as the "Disc type". The main DVD title should start playback (without menus)
- Drag and drop the *.srt file onto the video to add it.

If you really want the menus, you'll need to [reauthor your DVD](http://forum.videohelp.com/topic338721.html) (see link for tools and instructions; this method primarily uses [Subtitle Creator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/subtitlecreator/) software) to add the subtitles from your .SRT into the stream.  You can play the result from your harddrive in VLC, or burn to DVDR.